# GestureDetector with onItemLongclick

Tags: android, android-layout

How can i integrate GestureDetector with onItemLongClick?

I have a GridView containing three images.  When I touch on the first image, I want to display a Toast message.  When I lift up my finger from the screen, I want to display a second Toast message.

I know that GestureDetector uses MotionEvent, but onItemLongClick does not.  But in this case, I would need to keep track of the image's position ID in the grid, thus it is not possible to implement inside onTouch()?

Comment: Why do you need longclick when all you want is onTouchEvent and sniff out the motion events you want.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Comment: hi, but if touch on first image, and drag my finger to the second image without lifting up my finger, will MotionEvent able to track this action?

If no, what class should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track the motion of the cursor, whether its a onscreen touch or a TrackBall move, using this class and if it crosses over into the next picture you can handle that event then.  Here is an example taken from the sdk examples:

```
    @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getActionMasked();
        if (action != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && action != MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            int N = event.getHistorySize();
            int P = event.getPointerCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < P; j++) {
                    mCurX = event.getHistoricalX(j, i);
                    mCurY = event.getHistoricalY(j, i);
                    drawPoint(mCurX, mCurY,
                            event.getHistoricalPressure(j, i),
                            event.getHistoricalTouchMajor(j, i));
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < P; j++) {
                mCurX = event.getX(j);
                mCurY = event.getY(j);
                drawPoint(mCurX, mCurY, event.getPressure(j), event.getTouchMajor(j));
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

You can read more and see the file in your SDK at C:\YourInstallDir\android-sdk\samples\android-10\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\graphics\TouchPaint.java or just search the whole examples files for MotionEvent there's a few more uses in them.

Comment: hi thanks for the example. i am wondering there is not method which i can keep track which element is in focus(as in tapped)?

Comment: Not sure you might have to handle that yourself or use some sort of Reflection to do that.